# Using LDAP Server on top of our database to allow iPhone / Blackberry Access

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ldap

We have ASP.NET contact database running on SQL Server.  We're not interested in syncing contacts (for a variety of reasons), but exploring using the LDAP connectors in the iPhone/Blackberry to allow users to see their database contacts on their mobile devices.

Is this idea feasible? I've never played around with LDAP before... Are there tools or servers that allow sycning of database(s) to an LDAP server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there are tools to do this but it's not too hard to write a tool which will perform the syncing you want, using a combination of SQL and script (for example VBScript or JScript).

Short story:

- Temporary/work tables populated from existing content of LDAP server (use ADSI to read).
- Use SQL code to compare and match these to your database entries to populate another table of "entries to create" and "entries to modify" (and "entries to delete" if you want that).
- From script perform the addition, updates and deletions.

Run the job periodically.

If your contact database has a modified date, you may be able to improve efficiency by having a "full sync" mode as above, and a "recent updates only" mode.

MS have an LDAP server you can play with called ADAM, if that helps. There are also open-source ones.